# Place icons anywhere on Droid Maxx

Tags: motorola-droid, app-icons

I have a Droid Maxx. Unlike any other Android device I've had, I cannot place app icons anywhere on the screen. They fill in towards the bottom of the screen, just like iOS.

Is there an option to turn this off?
Failing that, is there an invisible icon app to use to fill in?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Long press the icon of the app and move it?

Comment: It slides back down when I do that.

Comment: Do you use any kind of launcher?

Comment: I do not use a launcher

Comment: Could you make a screenshot of display settings?

Comment: added screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Long hold on the app icon, and drag it to the remove button the appears on top of the screen. This will put it in the app drawer, but it will stay on the phone.